# SQL Query to combine rows from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table, lets call it Master.

```
+--------+------+------+
| Master | Name | Vaue |
+--------+------+------+
|    101 | A    |   12 |
|    202 | B    |   14 |
|    303 | C    |   12 |
|    404 | D    |   18 |
|    505 | E    |   16 |
+--------+------+------+
```

And I have a second table called Steps.

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| StepID | MasterID | Time  |
+--------+----------+-------+
|      1 |      101 | 14:53 |
|      2 |      101 | 15:24 |
|      1 |      202 | 02:23 |
|      2 |      202 | 05:15 |
|      3 |      202 | 07:42 |
|      1 |      303 | 22:10 |
|      2 |      303 | 22:15 |
|      1 |      505 | 11:59 |
|      2 |      505 | 12:25 |
|      3 |      505 | 12:48 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

I would like to make query to adding 3 columns(3 StepID) with time values to Master table.

First column is with time values where Master.MasterID = Steps.MasterID and StepID = 1.

Second column is with time values where Master.MasterID = Steps.MasterID and StepID = 2.

Third column is with time values where Master.MasterID = Steps.MasterID and StepID = 3.

Created table must have the same number of rows as Master table.

```
+--------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| Master | Name | Vaue | Time1 | Time2 | Time3 |
+--------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|    101 | A    |   12 | 14:53 | 15:24 | -     |
|    202 | B    |   14 | 02:23 | 05:15 | 07:42 |
|    303 | C    |   12 | 22:10 | 22:15 | -     |
|    404 | D    |   18 | -     | -     | -     |
|    505 | E    |   16 | 11:59 | 12:25 | 12:48 |
+--------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: you want to change the columns or make a select?

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.Master, m.Name, m.Value,  
       max(case when s.StepId = 1 then s.Time else NULL end) as Time1,
       max(case when s.StepId = 2 then s.Time else NULL end) as Time2,
       max(case when s.StepId = 3 then s.Time else NULL end) as Time3
from Master m left join Steps s on m.Master = s.MasterID
group by m.Master, m.Name, m.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine separate joins for each step and use query similar to this:

```
SELECT m.Master, m.Name, m.Value, s1.Time as Time1, s2.Time as Time2, s3.Time as Time3
FROM Master m
    LEFT JOIN Steps s1 ON m.Master = s1.MasterID AND s1.StepId = 1
    LEFT JOIN Steps s2 ON m.Master = s2.MasterID AND s2.StepId = 2
    LEFT JOIN Steps s3 ON m.Master = s3.MasterID AND s3.StepId = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server another way to do this is to use the`pivot`operator:

```
select 
    Master,
    Name,
    Value, 
    [1] as Time1, 
    [2] as Time2, 
    [3] as Time3 
from Master m
left join Steps s on m.Master = s.MasterID
pivot (
    max ([Time]) for StepID IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS p
```